# Sorting Data in Table by Column mysql and wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort the table by scores in ascending order.

Here is the table :

Here is the code I'm using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores";
  $myData = mysql_query($sql);

  echo "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
        <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        </tr>";

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . urldecode($record['email']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['score'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
?>
<?php
    $str="@";
    echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Comment: use ORDER BY on your query.

Comment: This question should not have been asked, 2 mins in google and you would have found your answer stack overflow is not for a "i can't be arsed looking im going to ask on SO" mentality. It will have taken you more time to write that post than https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Mysql+order&oq=Mysql+order&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5184j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `SQL` statement to include an `ORDER BY` clause

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores";
```

Should turn into

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores
        ORDER BY score ASC";
```

Where score is the column you want to sort by, and ASC is the order of the data

Comment: That worked.  I though I had tried that already and was getting an error the first time.  But that seemed to work, thanks for your help.